# What is an easy query to fix up historical columns valid_from and valid_to?

Tags: mysql, oracle

I have a table with typical history rows using valid_from and valid_to dates.  My table might look like this:

```
| id | object_id | name | valid_from | valid_to
--------------------------------------------------
|  1 | 1000      | Foo  | 2010-07-01 |   null
|  2 | 1000      | Bar  | 2011-12-31 |   null
|  3 | 2000      | Baz  | 2010-08-04 |   null
|  4 | 2000      | Bang | 2013-03-21 |   null
```

I'd like run a SQL update such that it would update valid_to of a row to next historical valid_from date minus 1 day if possible.  So therefore the table might look like this when the query is done:

```
| id | object_id | name | valid_from | valid_to
--------------------------------------------------
|  1 | 1000      | Foo  | 2010-07-01 |   2011-12-30
|  2 | 1000      | Bar  | 2011-12-31 |   null
|  3 | 2000      | Baz  | 2010-08-04 |   2013-03-20
|  4 | 2000      | Bang | 2013-03-21 |   null
```

I've tried a few different variations, but I'm striking out on this one:

```
select * 
from employees as cur 
where cur.valid_from < (
    select nx.valid_from from employees as nx 
    where 
       cur.source_id=nx.source_id 
       and nx.valid_from > cur.valid_from
);
```

And

```
update employees cur 
set cur.valid_to = (
    select nx.valid_from 
    from employees nx 
    where cur.source_id=nx.source_id 
          and nx.valid_from > cur.valid_from
);
```

Part of the problem with the subquery as I've written it is that it will return multiple rows.  I just need the very first row that occurs after the valid_from of the current row.  And the update statement MySQL complains that cur.valid_from cannot be used in the subquery.

I'm trying to find a query that would be portable between Oracle and MySQL.  Can someone get me on the right track?

Comment: You should look at the `lag`/`lead` "analytic" functions for Oracle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There a lot of differences between the two DBMS.

- Oracle supports window fundtions, the `MERGE` statement and several other features that MySQL doesn't.
- They have different datetime functions (but you are lucky here, `- interval '1' day`  will work in both).
- Different `UPDATE` syntax - apart from very simple, one table update statements.

  - MySQL supports a `JOIN` in the `UPDATE` statement, Oracle doesn't.
  - Oracle supports updatable "views" (derived tables), MySQL doesn't.
  - MySQL doesn't allow the updated table to be defined (again) in a subquery in the update `WHERE`.

Therefore, it will be very difficult - if possible at all - to write an update statement that will work in both dbms for youe complex case.

For Oracle, you can use either a `MERGE` statement, or the `LEAD()` function (altough I didn't manage to make it work in your case) or a self-join, or an inline subquery in an updatable "view":

[SQLfiddle-1](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a3d88/1)

```
update
( select id, valid_to, 
         ( select min(ee.valid_from)
           from employees ee
           where ee.object_id = e.object_id
             and ee.valid_from > e.valid_from
         ) as next_valid
  from employees e
) 
set valid_to = next_valid - interval '1' day ;
```

or with the more simple:

```
update employees e
set valid_to = 
   ( select min(valid_from)
     from employees u
     where u.object_id = e.object_id
       and u.valid_from > e.valid_from
   ) - interval '1' day ;
```

None of the above will work in mysql.

---

For MySQL it will have to be something more convoluted:

```
update
    employees e
  join
    ( select id, 
         ( select min(ee.valid_from)
           from employees ee
           where ee.object_id = ei.object_id
             and ee.valid_from > ei.valid_from
         ) as next_valid
      from employees ei
    ) upd
    on e.id = upd.id
set e.valid_to = upd.next_valid - interval 1 day ;
```

Another possibility for MySQL is using a variable (will update with an example later).

---

I think your only option, if you truly want something that works in both environments, is to break the problem into two actions:

- 1, insert the values into a temporary table and
- 2, do the actual update using that temp table.

Comment: Thank you both of those were exactly on.  I decided to add dialect specific feature so I could switch between the two queries to be portable.

Comment: UPDATEable/INSERTable VIEWs in MySQL:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/view-updatability.html

Comment: @RickJames thx, you are right, I was not accurate there, will edit later. Both Oracle's and MySQL's updatable views have many limitattions though,

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, portability between RDBMSs is a hopeless goal.

In one job, where we were considering moving from Sybase to Oracle, I went through the code and estimated that 80% of the SQL-related *lines* would need to be changed.

Some 'insurmountable' differences (Oracle vs MySQL):

- ROWNUM vs LIMIT
- CLOB vs TEXT
- INDEXes (OK, there may be a tiny subset that is common.)
- FULLTEXT, SPATIAL, etc (at least the syntax and api is different)
- Character set handling.  (MySQL has a few kludges, such as equating VARCHAR2 and NVARCHAR to its VARCHAR).

Even if you could write in a common subset of two RDBMSs, you would soon learn how much you are giving up in one or the other in order to be "common".

**A better solution**:  Build a "Database layer" between your application and the database.  Design the API to the layer so that you avoid any mention of issues that exist in only one engine.  For example, don't talk in terms of either `LIMIT` or `ROWNUM`, pick some abstraction that is closer to the application.

If you do a good job with the API, you can minimize the conversion effort (which will never happen, anyway), while being able to access some of the unique features of the RDBMS you start with.